# How to understand the pronunciation of informal English?

Tags: pronunciation, formality

I moved to English speaking country a while ago. I always thought that my English is pretty well in both speaking and listening (understanding) parts.

I understand 100% what is being said for example at planning sessions at work, on a meeting, during the working day. But when it comes to informal English I just stop understand a half of what has been said. I hear that almost all words are pronounced looks like they've been 'eaten' in half.

For example: "in there" sound for me like "innair" or "how do you handle that?" like "howdu hanledat'?".

I there somewhere Lungmoon Dictinoory or something?

It really bothers me a lot :(

Comment: FWIW, learners of a language in a country where it is spoken natively often have the same problem. For one thing, people talk fast and indistinctly - they are only as distinct as they need to be for their interlocutors. For another thing, a foreigner has often learned "school" language first, or instead of, the informal way that people actually speak much of the time.

Comment: It varies a lot depending on where you are and who you are talking to.  Some localities have very strong accents and a tradition of talking fast and/or slurring words, but in other localities this is not so noticeable.  And, of course, if you are talking to someone in a formal (eg, business) environment they will tend to speak more "properly".  But to a large degree it's just a matter of learning the local dialect.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that the question is too broad and that a concise answer is not possible.  Both David Garner and I answered basically the same way, a few hours apart, with what we apparently both believe is the best way to approach this problem (which doesn't seem to be a complex question).  David McKnight mentions something similar, with a few other ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, people are not going to change their habits to make it easier for you to understand them when they are not speaking carefully.  The same thing happens in all languages, including your native language, whatever it is.

That being said, my suggestion for you is to watch a lot of television.  Put on the closed captions and read along as the people speak.  This will help you to understand when people say "Jeet jet?" and mean "Did you eat yet?"

Comment: +1. OP: You will also find, I'm sure, that it is much easier talking one-on-one with someone. Then you can ask for clarification, and the other person generally makes more efforts to communicate with *you*. It can be very hard to follow a conversation (e.g. at the lunch table) among native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no definite dictionary for such things, depending on the region, there may be specific books on the accent. There are ways to check to see how far off of normal English the pronunciation is, however, through checking dictionaries like Dictionary.com (which has audio samples) and Wikipedia (which has audio and IPA for a couple of kinds of English, depending on the word) (if you want to attempt to learn how to use IPA, it's quite helpful for learning new languages, but is confusing for beginners). Listening to the local radio or news may help with improving comprehension, as well.

Comment: Incidentally, if it makes you feel any better, I'm a native English speaker in college (received a perfect score on both English sections of the ACT) and I have a good deal of difficulty with understanding certain accents (for example, deep Southeastern United States and Scouse).

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest, if it's available where you live, watching TV with subtitles (close captions)? Your reading ability in English probably exceeds your ability to follow spoken English, so if you watch (say) a sitcom, the subtitles might help you catch what's being said.